# Снова про основу - "Их так много"

Tags: синтаксис

**Их так много.** А здесь какая основа?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Это безличное предложение. Грамматическая основа - сказуемое "много"

Answer (score 1):

Сказуемое "много", связка-нулевая (глагол-связка есть подразумевается), тип сказуемого-составное именное. Предложение безличное.